# Error in first application in android studio

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

I'm new to android development after installing android studio to build my first project i faced this error.

[image: see picture]

I'm using Linux mint 18 and i had install oracle jdk

> java version "1.8.0_101"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Did you setup the SDK Manager?

Comment: no , just installing oracle jdk and android studio and android studio download files but i don't know what its name i'm new in android development and its my first time to work with android studio

Comment: In the image... `android-studio/jre/bin/java` means that you are not setup to use your system installed Oracle JDK, but rather the JRE that comes with Studio

Comment: can you tell me what i should do to make it work ? i have linux mint alongside with windows 7

Comment: Operating system isn't important here. First, I think you need to download the Android API version you are developing for. I believe that is under Window > Android > SDK Manager. Then, you have to go into the settings for the IDE and the the Project SDK is correct

Comment: click on (File --> project Structure --> SDK Location) and post a screenshot to check  -- you need (jdk1.8.0_92) or whatever new version there is from oracle -- should look like this although im on windows so the directory structure will differ -- https://s22.postimg.org/uvaccukup/Capture.png

Comment: if you havent installed the JDK or you didnt follow the correct setup then check here on how to -- should be the same for Linux Mint -- http://justinalex.com/operating-systems/linux/install-oracle-java-jdk-in-ubuntu-and-debian/

Comment: see this picture https://s16.postimg.org/rrfw2k2hx/Screenshot_from_2016_10_09_21_02_12.png